# firebase data recyclerview sometimes show nothing

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I trying to show firebase data by using recyclerview.

retrieving data is well, I can check it in logcat.

Sometimes recyclerview show data, but **Usually show nothing.**

When recycleview show data, it is reflectled firebase data well.

Who can tell me What the problem?? Is there mistake in my xml code?

**Java code**

```
artistData.child(starList[i]).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot starDataSnap) {
        int fanNums = (int) starDataSnap.child("fanNums").getValue(Integer.class);
        int placeNums = (int) starDataSnap.child("placeNums").getValue(Integer.class);

        Log.d("####", finalStarName + fanNums + placeNums);
        drawerStarImage = getResources().getIdentifier(finalStarImgName, "drawable", getActivity().getPackageName());
        ItemStarData itemStarData = new ItemStarData();
        itemStarData.setStarImage(drawerStarImage);
        itemStarData.setStarName(finalStarName);
        itemStarData.setFanNums(fanNums);
        itemStarData.setPlaceNums(placeNums);

        drawerStarList.add(itemStarData);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
    }

});
```

**Adapter class code**

```
public class AdapterStarlist extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterStarlist.ViewHolder>{
    ArrayList<ItemStarData> array;
    Context context;


public AdapterStarlist(ArrayList<ItemStarData> array, Context context) {
    this.array = array;
    this.context =context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public AdapterStarlist.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_home_starlist,parent,false);
    return new AdapterStarlist.ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AdapterStarlist.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Log.d("####", array.get(position).getStarName());
    holder.Imgstarlist.setImageResource(array.get(position).getStarImage());
    holder.followStarName.setText(String.valueOf(array.get(position).getStarName()));
    holder.starlistfanNum.setText(String.valueOf(array.get(position).getFanNums()));
    holder.starlistPlaceNum.setText(String.valueOf(array.get(position).getPlaceNums()));

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return array.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView Imgstarlist;
    TextView followStarName;
    TextView starlistfanNum;
    TextView starlistPlaceNum;


    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        Imgstarlist =itemView.findViewById(R.id.Imgstarlist);
        followStarName =itemView.findViewById(R.id.followStarName);
        starlistfanNum =itemView.findViewById(R.id.starlistfanNum);
        starlistPlaceNum =itemView.findViewById(R.id.starlistPlaceNum);

        Imgstarlist.setBackground(new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape()));
        Imgstarlist.setClipToOutline(true);
    }
}

}
```

**Part of xml code**

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="480dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/DrawerStarlist"
        >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rlDrawerStarlist"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/DrawerStarlist">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rvDrawerStarlist"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                />


        </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're adding the data to the `drawerStarList` list, but not telling the adapter that you've done so. Until you tell the adapter of the change (by calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` on it), it won't repaint the UI for the list.

So typically this would look something like:

```
artistData.child(starList[i]).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot starDataSnap) {
        ...

        drawerStarList.add(itemStarData);

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // tell the adapter to repaint its views
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        throw error.toException(); // never ignore errors
    }
});
```

With `adapter` being a reference to the adapter that you use to manage `drawerStarList`.

Comment: Oh no. I added this "adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); " outside of addValueEventListener before. Now it works well!!! Thank you so much :D